# In MATE, how do I get different panels per workspace?

Tags: mate-desktop, workspaces, panel

I'm running MATE 1.8 in Linux Mint 17 Qiana. I have three workspaces set up, and panels at the top and bottom of the screen. I have a bunch of items in the top panels that launch various applications and documents etc.

Is it possible to get the set of items to differ per-workspace, by having either panels or items in them only show up in particular workspaces?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I tried it and found out it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm working on another solution and will post it here if I get it working.